# How do I call a method as a parameter from a subclass in the Object class in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method inside a service class:

```
@override
  Future<String> registerNewVoter(Object deviceAppInfo) async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    final url = API().endpointVoterUri(EndpointVoter.newVoter).toString();
    final header = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
    final data = await deviceAppInfo; ///need to call the method getInfo() on the Object class which returns a future

    final response =
        await dio.post(url, data: data, options: Options(headers: header));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map map = response.data;
      final uuid = map['result']['voter_uuid'];
      return uuid;
    }
    print(
        'Request $url failed\nResponse: ${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage}');
    throw response;
  }
```

I'm using type `Object deviceAppInfo` as a parameter in the method to keep the service as pure as possible(adhering to mvvm principles). The subclass is `DeviceAppInfo` which has an async method called `getInfo()`(and where the data comes from) which is supposed to be assigned to data(see the comments in the code). I'm struggling to see how I can keep the class decoupled from DeviceAppInfo class. Any suggestions...? I'm thinking of calling a factory constructor but not sure how to implement it. Here is my DeviceAppInfo class:

```
class DeviceAppInfo {
  DeviceAppInfo({
    this.platform,
    this.platformVersion,
    this.appVersion,
  });


  final String platform;
  final String platformVersion;
  final String appVersion;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'platform': this.platform,
        'platform_version': this.platformVersion,
        'app_version': this.appVersion,
      };

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getInfo() async {
    final values = await Future.wait([
      getPlatform(),
      getPlatformVersion(),
      getProjectVersion(),
    ]);

    return DeviceAppInfo(
      platform: values[0],
      platformVersion: values[1],
      appVersion: values[2],
    ).toMap();
  }

  Future<String> getPlatform() async {
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        return 'ios';
      }
      return 'android';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  Future<String> getPlatformVersion() async {
    try {
      final platformVersion = await GetVersion.platformVersion;
      return platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  Future<String> getProjectVersion() async {
    try {
      final projectVersion = await GetVersion.projectVersion;
      return projectVersion;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that DeviceAppInfo is a clear collaborator of your service, and hiding it behind Object is simply bad engineering:

- it will make your Api hard to use correctly and easy to use incorrectly
- Your api is no longer self-documenting, without reading the docs or code it is impossible to use it correctly.

However, it can be discussed if it should be exposed as a parameter or provided to the constructor of your service.

Having said that, There are at least 3 options that will decouple your service from DeviceAppInfo:

**Option 1: Pass in the result of getInfo() to your method**

- least questionable and a common form of decoupling inbound data
- I am a bit sceptical if you use a Map as an input type, it is still easy to provide a map with incorrect keys

**Option 2: take a function as an argument**

- Function a bit harder to use, it is not evident what functions accross the codebase can be used (compared to a class)

**Option 3: cast to dynamic**

Please dont do that

- Most closely matches your goal from question
- function is extremely hard to use correctly Without reading docs / code
- You change compile-time errors to runtime errors

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
@override
  Future<String> registerNewVoter(DeviceAppInfo deviceAppInfo) async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    final url = API().endpointVoterUri(EndpointVoter.newVoter).toString();
    final header = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
    final data = await deviceAppInfo.getInfo();

    final response =
        await dio.post(url, data: data, options: Options(headers: header));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map map = response.data;
      final uuid = map['result']['voter_uuid'];
      return uuid;
    }
    print(
        'Request $url failed\nResponse: ${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage}');
    throw response;
  }
```

NOTE: I just changed the type of **deviceAppInfo** from `Object` to `DeviceAppInfo`

Comment: That will work. But  I need to keep the class pure.In another class I'm introducing DeviceAppInfo.  I'm decoupling  the class from my Api. But thanks anyway.